# Exchange Server 2013 logs and location

Tags: logging, exchange-server-2013

I'm looking for the location of Exchange Server 2013 logs, and I can't find it on Microsoft's site and I'm not able to Google it as well.

Does anyone have a URL where all of Exchange Server 2013's logs and locations are listed?

Answer (score 0):

log file location really does depend on if you changed these. Usually OWA, Hub etc. are held with the Exchange install directory / CAS or /Transport.
I hope that helps

You could also find database log locations (which normally would be in the same directory as database) by either using powershell or viewing the database information via CP